# Try to get <li> element by xpath with selenium,but get Message: element not interactable

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm doing the web GUI automation of a web page,when I try to get the first

element,it always print "element not interactable".The code of the page is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8o95.png)

My xpath is :

```
  element =self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul/li[text()="Portal"]')
```

I can get "RADIUS" clicked by xpath `'//ul/li[text()="RADIUS"]'`,but I get `"element not interactable"` by xpath `'//ul/li[text()="Portal"]'`.I don't know what's the different between element "RADIUS" and "Portal"

Comment: Xpath=//li[text()='Portal'] try this xpath it will work

Comment: It's still not work,always "element not interactable".I need to check "Portal" under the condition that "RADIUS" has already been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some whitespace in the text value of that `<li>` element, so `text()` will not match `'Portal'`. Try using [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) instead:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul/li[contains(text(),"Portal")]')
```

Comment: I found that there are same elements on the page,so the xpath I used can't locate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, verify that the element you are trying to click is visible on the page.
   you need to open drop down first and then click the value you want to select.

Comment: Not need to open Dropdown it will automatically select by XPath because when a page is a load it will also load li and option tag contents.

Comment: yes on page load li and option tag will be loaded but element you want to click should be visible on the page. 
Otherwise, it will throw *element not interactable* error.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//li[text()='Portal']")
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21273814)